# strdup или malloc?

Tags: c, malloc

Есть указатель на массив чар, к примеру **char *content;**

Нужно его заполнить информацией, что будет правильнее?

1. content = strdup("TEXT");
   free(content);
2. content = malloc(strlen("TEXT") + 1);
   strcpy(content, "TEXT");
   free(content);

Что в первом, что во втором варианте valgrind ругается на отсутствие освобождение памяти при завершении программы.

Вариант **char *content = "TEXT";** не подходит из-за того что переменная content часть структуры, которая многократно изменяется в ходе работы.

Comment: 2 - по сути просто реализация 1. Так что используйте, что вам внутренне ближе :) А проблема - лично у меня подозрение, что она связана не с применением этих функций, а с чем-то иным...

Comment: 10 bytes in 2 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 31 of 1,499
at 0x483877F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
by 0x50EA6FE: strdup (in /usr/lib/libc-2.29.so)
by 0x48926A0: json_object_object_add_ex (in /usr/lib/libjson-c.so.4.0.0)
by 0x489522A: json_tokener_parse_ex (in /usr/lib/libjson-c.so.4.0.0)
by 0x48969E8: json_tokener_parse_verbose (in /usr/lib/libjson-c.so.4.0.0)
by 0x4896A4E: json_tokener_parse (in /usr/lib/libjson-c.so.4.0.0)

Вот вывод валгринда, подозреваю что это из-за отсутствия высвобождения памяти.

Comment: Ну так вы освобождаете память через `free`? Или нет?

Comment: В ходе выполнения программы да, но по ее завершению через ctrl+c valgrind показывает отсутствие освобождения памяти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй вариант "правильнее" тем, что не использует нестандартную функцию `strdup`. Разумеется, имеет смысл позаботиться о том, чтобы не выписывать явно один и тот же строковый литерал два раза.

Comment: Было бы интересно узнать, как можно `позаботиться о том, чтобы не выписывать явно один и тот же строковый литерал два раза`

Comment: @Andrei Khotko: Объявить именованную константу, макрос, переменную и т.п.

Comment: Ааа, вы это имели ввиду. Я немного неправильно вас понял